# ASP.NET MVC "GET" and "POST" constants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constants

Does ASP.NET MVC have any constants for the the strings "GET" and "POST"?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a little redundant?  Descriptive string literals are basically constants on their own.

Comment: Where are you looking to use them? Typically it's better to make use of `HttpVerbs.Get` and `HttpVerbs.Post`

Comment: In which context? `AcceptVerbs`? `Html.BeginForm`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Comparing with HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod requires a string.  Also the array parameter of AcceptVerbs requires strings.

Comment: Thats not true, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283209/asp-net-mvc-acceptverbs-and-registering-routes, hence why they made the HttpVerbs enumeration in the MVC namespace.

Comment: Yes it is true... read what I said carefully... "the ARRAY parameter of AccetpVerbs requires strings"... I want to accept more than one verb... there is no way to do that with HttpVerbs.

Comment: Yes you can.  HttpVerbs is a bit flag enumeration, if you want to accept more than 1 type you just have to OR them together, `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.GET | HttpVerbs.POST)]`, regardless if you want to use strings, you are correct that my answer is not the solution you asked for.

Comment: Wow, that is cool... I will switch to using that bit flag enumeration for AcceptVerbs. Thanks! However I still need the string to compare with HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use the [`System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.http_members.aspx) class.  (`WebRequestMethods.Http.Get` and `WebRequestMethods.Http.Post`)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't have "OPTIONS".

Answer (score 7):

Yes HttpVerbs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(VS.100).aspx

Comment: If you're looking for strings, see my answer.

Comment: You could use ToString, like this: HttpVerbs.Delete.ToString()