# Adding Create method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When i add 2 Create Method in my controller like below

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Product.Models.Product p = new Models.Product();
       //update DB
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return View(p);
        }

    } 

    //
    // POST: /Product/Default1/Create

     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Posr)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (myProduct.Products == null)
            {
                myProduct.Products = new List<Models.Product>();
            }
            Product.Models.Product p = new Product.Models.Product();
            p.Name =  collection["Name"];
            p.ProductType = collection["ProductType"];
            p.Id = myProduct.Products.Count + 1;

            myProduct.Products.Add(p);


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

If i Comment GET action verbs and run application, application throws error resource not found. It will not fire Create Action. my html has  @using (Html.BeginForm())

I Changed Form to    even then i get same error. If i uncomment GET action verb, then always GET method fires up. I want call POST Create action . Can any1 directme how to solve.

I have Product has Areas in my MVC project. within in it has ProductsController.cs Please help me how to call POST action Create method.

-Mahender

Comment: You have a type on the AcceptVerbs attribute for the post. ".Posr" -> ".Post"

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283209/asp-net-mvc-acceptverbs-and-registering-routes

Comment: I was able to understand meaning of having 2 methods with different verbs in ASP.NET MVC. But the question is how to force always use the POST in MVC. Is there any HTTP Constraint , I need to set in routing strategy

Comment: if you comment out the GET Create method, how are you gonna post then form back to POST Create method?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Default1", new { area = "Product" }, FormMethod.Post)) {
// Your Form
}
```

And please use

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
```

instead of AcceptVerbs, its much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet] // Or even if you dont put this, it will be treated as GET
public ActionResult Create()
{
     // your code goes here
}

[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult Create(Model yourModel)
{
    // your code goes here 
}

in your view 
@using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")
```